# Trouble displaying Tic Tac Toe game board in JavaScript/HTML/CSS project

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm still in school and new to coding and programming. I've watched a video tutorial on how to build Tic Tac Toe using javascript,css and html. I used Visual Studio Code, and after imputing the relevant codes I used Live Server to test the game out.
The problem is that only the title and a reset button pops up, the game board and the actual game is not there.

I tried double-checking the codes, though I am not a coding expert, I am merely a beginner thus I need some expert advice, solutions, and guidance.

Here are the codes I used:

HTML CODE:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
    <div id="board">
      <div class="square" id="0"></div>
      <div class="square" id="1"></div>
      <div class="square" id="2"></div>
      <div class="square" id="3"></div>
      <div class="square" id="4"></div>
      <div class="square" id="5"></div>
      <div class="square" id="6"></div>
      <div class="square" id="7"></div>
      <div class="square" id="8"></div>
    </div>
    <button id="reset">Reset Game</button>
  </div>`
```

CSS code:

```
`.container {
  text-align: center;
}

#board {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.square {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.square:hover {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.square.X {
  color: #ff5e5e;
}

.square.O {
  color: #0077ff;
}
`
```

JavaScript code:

```
`let board = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
let currentPlayer = "X";
let gameOver = false;

const winningConditions = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6]
];

const squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
const resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset");

// Add click event listener to each square
squares.forEach(square => {
  square.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
});

// Add click event listener to reset button
resetButton.addEventListener("click", resetGame);

function handleClick(event) {
  const square = event.target;
  const index = square.getAttribute("id");

  // If square is already clicked or game is over, return
  if (board[index] !== "" || gameOver) {
    return;
  }

  // Add X or O to board and update UI
  board[index] = currentPlayer;
  square.classList.add(currentPlayer);
  square.innerHTML = currentPlayer;

  // Check for winner or tie game
  checkForWinner();
  checkForTieGame();

  // Switch current player
  currentPlayer = currentPlayer === "X" ? "O" : "X";
}

function checkForWinner() {
  for (let i = 0; i < winningConditions.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = winningConditions[i];
    if (board[a] === board[b] && board[b] === board[c] && board[a] !== "") {
      gameOver = true;
      highlightWinnerSquares(a, b, c);
      displayWinner(board[a]);
      break;
    }
  }
}

function checkForTieGame() {
  if (!board.includes("") && !gameOver) {
    gameOver = true;
    displayTieGame();
  }
}

function highlightWinnerSquares(a, b, c) {
  document.getElementById(a).classList.add("winner");
  document.getElementById(b).classList.add("winner");
  document.getElementById(c).classList.add("winner");
}

function displayWinner(player) {
  const message = document.getElementById("message");
  message.innerHTML = `${player} wins!`;
}

function displayTieGame() {
  const message = document.getElementById("message");
  message.innerHTML = "It's a tie game!";
}

function resetGame() {
  board = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
  currentPlayer = "X";
  gameOver = false;

  squares.forEach(square => {
    square.classList.remove("X", "O", "winner");
    square.innerHTML = "";
  });

  const message = document.getElementById("message");
  message.innerHTML = "";
}
`
```

Comment: Where are the closing tags for `<body>` and `<html>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TO put the answer by Urax more clearly please update your HTML to the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
    <div id="board">
      <div class="square" id="0"></div>
      <div class="square" id="1"></div>
      <div class="square" id="2"></div>
      <div class="square" id="3"></div>
      <div class="square" id="4"></div>
      <div class="square" id="5"></div>
      <div class="square" id="6"></div>
      <div class="square" id="7"></div>
      <div class="square" id="8"></div>
    </div>
    <button id="reset">Reset Game</button>
    <div id="message"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
let board = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
let currentPlayer = "X";
let gameOver = false;

const winningConditions = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6]
];

const squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
const resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset");

// Add click event listener to each square
squares.forEach(square => {
  square.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
});

// Add click event listener to reset button
resetButton.addEventListener("click", resetGame);

function handleClick(event) {
  const square = event.target;
  const index = square.getAttribute("id");

  // If square is already clicked or game is over, return
  if (board[index] !== "" || gameOver) {
    return;
  }

  // Add X or O to board and update UI
  board[index] = currentPlayer;
  square.classList.add(currentPlayer);
  square.innerHTML = currentPlayer;

  // Check for winner or tie game
  checkForWinner();
  checkForTieGame();

  // Switch current player
  currentPlayer = currentPlayer === "X" ? "O" : "X";
}

function checkForWinner() {
  for (let i = 0; i < winningConditions.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = winningConditions[i];
    if (board[a] === board[b] && board[b] === board[c] && board[a] !== "") {
      gameOver = true;
      highlightWinnerSquares(a, b, c);
      displayWinner(board[a]);
      break;
    }
  }
}

function checkForTieGame() {
  if (!board.includes("") && !gameOver) {
    gameOver = true;
    displayTieGame();
  }
}

function highlightWinnerSquares(a, b, c) {
  document.getElementById(a).classList.add("winner");
  document.getElementById(b).classList.add("winner");
  document.getElementById(c).classList.add("winner");
}

function displayWinner(player) {
  const message = document.getElementById("message");
  message.innerHTML = `${player} wins!`;
}

function displayTieGame() {
  const message = document.getElementById("message");
  message.innerHTML = "It's a tie game!";
}

function resetGame() {
  board = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
  currentPlayer = "X";
  gameOver = false;

  squares.forEach(square => {
    square.classList.remove("X", "O", "winner");
    square.innerHTML = "";
  });

  const message = document.getElementById("message");
  message.innerHTML = "";
}
```

The CSS is fine.

Hope this helps. Original answer is by Urax, I just rephrased his answer for your convenience.

Comment: Thank you both for the feedback.
I did fix everything you mentioned, I think all the codes are fine now. However, in my browser only the title and the the reset button appears again:(

Do you maybe think I should use another extension instead of Live Server?

Comment: I have updated the original answer with actual snippet that I tested and found correct. It only needed an extra division with id message in HTML. You do not need to open using Live server or something similar. Simply open the HTML file in a browser. Make sure to name the HTML file as `index.html`, JS file as `index.js` and CSS file as `style.css`. All 3 files must be in the same folder.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just realized that I named it index.css instead of style.css. I opened it in the browser, the gameboard appears however when I click on the tiles it does not seem to input the X or the O's thus I cannot play the game.

Comment: Can you kindly use the code I shared in my answer? It will work.

Comment: You need to click on the reset game button in order to start the game. Please spend some time understanding what you coded.

Comment: @PrashanthPuranik Thanks for further clarifying the solution. Your answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Link the javascript code with:
`<script src="path_to_file.js"></script>`
As well as finish the body and html tags.